# Random Images without Links

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to make the below javascript just display the random images with out a link?

```
var imagenumber = 10 ;
var randomnumber = Math.random() ;
var rand1 = Math.round( (imagenumber-1) * randomnumber) + 1 ;
var URLs = new Array() ;
images = new Array
images[1] = "images/headerpics/fall/fall17.png"
images[2] = "images/headerpics/fall/fall1.png"
images[3] = "images/headerpics/fall/fall2.png"
images[4] = "images/headerpics/fall/fall3.png"
images[5] = "images/headerpics/fall/fall4.png"
images[6] = "images/headerpics/fall/fall5.png"
images[7] = "images/headerpics/fall/fall6.png"
images[8] = "images/headerpics/fall/fall7.png"
images[9] = "images/headerpics/fall/fall8.png"
images[10] = "images/headerpics/fall/fall9.png"

var image = images[rand1] ;
var linknumber = 1 ;
var img1 = Math.round( (linknumber-1) * randomnumber) + 1 ;
links = new Array
links[1] = "index.htm"

var link = links[img1];
document.write('<a href="' + link + '"><img src="' + image + '"   
border="0"></a>') ;
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: just dont write the `<a>` tag

Comment: Won't the removal of anchor tag will suffice your requirement?
`document.write(<img src="' + image + '"   
border="0">') ;`

Comment: I removed, document.write('<a href="' + link + '"><img src="' + image + '" border="0"></a>') ; and then tried just removing the '<a href="' + link + '"><img src="' + image + '" border="0"></a> but then nothing shows up.

Comment: There is no way you could have written this code if you don't understand the HTML, this isn't a homework assignment is it?

Comment: Yes there is, and it's really easy, you have to explain what you've tried and what is the problem you are encountering. Otherwise, as others have posted, this is too basic a question and shows no understanding or attempt to understand the code you are touching.

Comment: My apologizes, I did not want a link associated with the random image.

Answer (score 0):

Just Remove the Anchor `(<a>)` tag from the `document.write`

```
document.write('<img src="' + image + '"border="0">');
```

Comment: That worked as expected.  Thank you!

I was thinking remove everything within the anchor tag, not just the tag itself.  Unfortunately, I am not much of a web designer but assigned the task of keeping our site up to date.